# How to "cast" an Object

Tags: c#, arrays, object, xna

I have a function that receives an array of Objects.

I also have a class called `Rectangle` but when I iterate the array of objects I need the Object in that index to be casted as Rectangle and not as object because the function I will use needs the parameter to be type Rectangle:

```
    //For collision handling - Receives one rectangle
    public bool IsColliding(Rectangle collisionRectangle)
    {
        return this.destinationRect.Intersects(collisionRectangle);
    }

    //Overloading - Receives an array with multiple Rectangles
    public bool IsColliding(Object[] collisionRectangles)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= collisionRectangles.Length; i++)
        {
            //CODE WILL FAIL HERE - The method "Intersects" requires and object of type Rectangle
            if(this.destinationRect.Intersects((Rectangle)collisionRectangles[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Declaration of the array before passing it to the function:

```
Object[] buildingCollitionRectangles =
        {
            new Rectangle[144, 16, 96, 32],
            new Rectangle[144, 48, 96, 64]
        };
```

Trying to use the method like this:

```
if(!player.IsColliding(buildingCollitionRectangles))
{
    updatePlayerInput();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Trying to store Rectangles in a Rectangle[] array:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of the `Rectangle` class?

Comment: Rectangle is a STRUCTURE in the XNA (Game Development Framework)

Comment: Any particular reason why `buildingCollitionRectangles` is an `object[]` rather than a `Rectangle[]`?  Just sayin

Comment: Mostly, I'm interested in the constructor - I'm not super strong on c#, but I've never seen a class that used square brackets `[]` rather than parentheses `[]` to initialize the values like that.

Comment: @MickyDuncan chek my question update number 2

Comment: Oh! It looks like you are allocating 4-dimensional arrays of `Rectangles` and trying to squeeze them into an one-dimensional array of `Rectangle`.  That's probably why the object[] worked

Comment: @MickyDuncan hmm, I'm new to C#, can you enlighten me?

Comment: OH WAIT, I think I know what's happening

Comment: `new Rectangle[144, 16, 96, 32]` should read `new Rectangle (144, 16, 96, 32)`.  Shove that into a `Rectangle[]`.  The same with the next line. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I think we found it - you used square brackets instead of parentheses for the `Rectangle` constructor.  As is, I think you're actually allocating two enormous multi-dimensional arrays of `Rectangle` objects.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.rectangle.aspx definitely shows you need parentheses.

Try this:

```
Rectangle[] buildingCollitionRectangles =
        {
            new Rectangle(144, 16, 96, 32),
            new Rectangle(144, 48, 96, 64)
        };
```

(Note that I think this should also solve the problem of not being able to use a `Rectangle[]` array)

Comment: Error: Specified cast is not valid

Comment: If that's the case, are you certain you're passing in an array of `Rectangle` objects?

Comment: Ok, this is it... I feel bad because in the end everything was just a sintax error. Yes I was using [] instead of ().

I think I need a cup of coffee and some rest, this is what happens when you program straight for hours.

Answer (score 2):

why not use Rectangle[] as your parameter's type?

Comment: Sadly that won't work because he was allocating a 4 dimensional `Rectangle` via square brackets rather than `( )` i.e. `new Rectangle[144, 48, 96, 64]` which won't fit into `Rectangle[]`.